# whenever gem: hourly tasks with minute set

Tags: cron, whenever

I have a bunch of cronjobs managed by whenever.  Everything works fine, but I have a few hourly cronjobs that are all triggered at the same time, so I'd like to stagger them.  Worst case scenario I'm able to update the crontab manually, but I'd really rather take of this in schedule.rb.

TL;DR - I would like to do something like:

```
every 1.hour, at: ":00" do #task 1
every 1.hour, at: ":10" do #task 2
every 1.hour, at: ":20" do #task 3
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 29):

This can be done this way:

```
every :hour, at: 0 do #task 1
every :hour, at: 10 do #task 2
every :hour, at: 20 do #task 3
```

Comment: Note, this does not work: `every :hour, at: 10.minutes`

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this for your case:

```
every '5 * * * *' do
  #do stuff here
end
```

This will launch at the 5 minute mark (every hour, every day, every month, every day of the week)

For other cases like this where whenever might not have a built in helper, check out [this link](http://team.macnn.com/drafts/crontab_defs.html)

Comment: This seems to  be an obvious feature.  Is there any obstacle to contributing this to the gem yet, or is it just that nobody's gotten around to it yet?